# Ускорение цикла по массиву с помощью numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Есть список скажем такого вида:

```
L = range(10000)
```

Нужно с каждым элементом списка что то проделать в зависимости от условия,
если список очень большой то стандартные питоновские циклы работают не так быстро как хотелось бы. Есть ли в numpy какие либо средства для итерации по спискам. К примеру есть функция:

```
def some_func(a):
    print('this is', a)
```

Нужно что бы эта функция применялась скажем к каждому не четному элементу списка, как это сделать не стандартным циклом, есть ли в numpy подобная возможность?

Comment: Если вы на каждый 2-й элемент делаете вывод, то скорость выполнения будет ограничена скоростью вывода на внешнее устройство (в файл или на консоль, причем на вывод на консоль будет намного медленнее, чем файл). Никакой Numpy тут не поможет. Если просто какие-то вычисления, то для 10000 элементов вычисления (если они не очень сложные) при помощи обычного for выполнятся практически мгновенно.

Comment: @insolor вывод не куда делать не нужно функция написана просто для примера, и число элементов массива написано для примера, само собой ясно что для 10 000 элементов мне ни какой numpy не нужен

Comment: Тогда покажите более реальный пример.

Comment: @insolor да просто нужно применять любую функцию к элементам списка по условию, только итерировать нужно не стандартным способом, а средствами numpy, если это возможно

Comment: `L = range(10000); z = [x if x % 2 == 0 else x ** 2 for x in L]` выполняется за сотые доли секунды. Пока что я не вижу, что тут можно ускорять.

Comment: @insolor более реальный пример займет гору строчек кода не кто здесь в нем разбираться не будет, суть вопроса в том что я написал и так понятна

Comment: @insolor повторю, число элементов массива написано для примера, само собой ясно что для 10 000 элементов мне ни какой numpy не нужен

Comment: Как раз лучше дать реальный конкретный пример, на котором есть смысл что-то ускорять. И количество элементов тогда уж напишите реальное.

Comment: @insolor вопрос банален, можно ли итерировать по массиву средствами numpy, ответ тоже, да или нет, и если да то название метода, мне больше ничего чего не нужно, не понимаю зачем нагружать здесь людей лишним кодом

Comment: Если поделать список на равные мини-списки и запустить это все в мультипроцессинг пуле?

Comment: @Alban интересуют не костыли, а именно более быстрое итерирование возможно вообще или нет с помощью numpy

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч боюсь это не возможно. И с мультипроцессингом вполне не костыль :)

Comment: @Alban очень жаль, думал в numpy есть какие либо итераторы

Comment: Дело в том, что само по себе итерирование практически мгновенно, дополнительно ускорять его не имеет смысла, да и нечего там уже ускорять, всё и так уже заоптимизировано до предела. То что действительно занимает время, так это код внутри цикла. А он не заработает быстрее, от того, что вы начнёте быстрее переходить между итерациями.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, сделайте как вам посоветовал insolor. Вся сила и прелесть Numpy в "vectorized ufuncs" (оптимизированных функциях написанных на C/Cython и поэтому очень быстрых). В общем случае в Numpy есть [apply_along_axis()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html), НО это тот же самый `for ...` цикл и по скорости он врядли будет быстрее. Зная конкретную задачу мы могли бы попробовать найти __векторизированное (быстрое)__ решение...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вся сила и прелесть Numpy в **vectorized ufuncs** (оптимизированных функциях написанных на `C`/`Cython` и поэтому очень быстрых). В общем случае в Numpy есть [vectorize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) для функций работающих со скалярами и [apply_along_axis()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) для функций работающих со списками, НО это тот же самый `for ...` цикл и по скорости он врядли будет быстрее. Зная конкретную задачу мы могли бы попробовать найти векторизированное (быстрое) решение...

Пример:

```
In [130]: a = np.random.randint(10**4, size=(10**6))

In [131]: import math

In [132]: def f(lst):
     ...:     return [math.sin(x) * math.cos(x) for x in lst]
     ...:

In [133]: a.shape
Out[133]: (1000000,)

In [134]: %timeit f(a[1::2])
866 ms ± 886 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [135]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, a[1::2])
932 ms ± 183 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Если ваша функция работает со **скалярами**:

```
In [137]: def f(x):
     ...:     return math.sin(x) * math.cos(x)
     ...:

In [138]: vfunc = np.vectorize(f)

In [139]: %timeit vfunc(a[1::2])
969 ms ± 19.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Векторизированное решение:

```
In [136]: %timeit np.sin(a[1::2]) * np.cos(a[1::2])
65.4 ms ± 92.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Вывод:** сначала надо постараться найти векторизированное решение. Если это невозможно, то следует сравнить другие варианты и, возможно, "`list comprehension`" окажется быстрее (как в приведенном мною примере)...